# NullPointerException: initialised variable suddenly null

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, null

I started programming with Java recently and am now experiencing following problem:

I wrote a class "ComparePattern", that derives a score of the best fit and should then give back the score and the best fitting pattern. No problem with the score so far. Giving back the pattern seems to not work though. It is an array of double-values, say "bestpattern". I have implemented a return-method to give back said double-array as well.

```
public void double[] getBestPattern(){return bestpattern;}
```

Now, after running the comparison, if I call the return-method from my main class (say MainClass) it returns an array which is null.

```
double[] test = ComparePattern.getBestPattern();
```

Doing something like

```
double[] test=ComparePattern.bestpattern;
```

gives null as well. However, if I print bestpattern right in the counstructor of my ComparePattern class, where it is generated, it is clearly not null but holds the expected values. Now comes the funny part. If I give the following instruction in the constructor of ComparePattern (after generating bestpattern of course) it works and gives back the correct values:

```
MainClass.test=bestpattern;
```

Obviously this is not the way I want to do this though. I have tried this in a static and a non-static way and I'm sure that all variables are initialised correctly. Anyone got an idea why java changes bestpattern from a functioning double-array to null?

Comment: Could you provide a SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Please provide your constructor and preferably your class code. I would hazard a guess that your `bestpattern` field is only scoped to your constructor and not to the class itself. Where are you defining `bestpattern`?

Comment: Did you forget `this` (like in `this.bestpattern = bestpattern`)?

Comment: Make getBestPattern() method as a static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably in the constructor of ComparePattern. It probably looks like this :

```
public class ComparePattern    
{
    private double[] bestpattern;
    ...
    public ComparePattern ()
    {
        ...
        double[] bestpattern = new double[..];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

which means that your construction initializes a local array named `bestpattern` instead of the member array with the same name. You should simply change it to :

```
public class ComparePattern    
{
    private double[] bestpattern;
    ...
    public ComparePattern ()
    {
        ...
        bestpattern = new double[..];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

That would explain why your `getBestPattern()` method returns null.